# Iterate text file contents in pyspark dataframe and generate the file with new dates in a list in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have below impala queries in one file in hdfs location.
I am trying to read that file and expand the file when I encounter the end_date as "2211-01-01"

list of dates are as

final_dates = ["2022-11-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-08-01"]

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-04-01"  and end_date < "2022-07-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-07-01"  and end_date < "2022-08-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-08-01"  and end_date < "2211-01-01";

file = spark.read.text("/usr/ihitha/var/hive/test_script.py").
How do I do above generate new queries with new dates which are in a list by reading the file in pyspark ?

expected output as below:-

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-04-01"  and end_date < "2022-07-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-07-01"  and end_date < "2022-08-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-08-01"  and end_date < "2022-11-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2022-11-01"  and end_date < "2023-02-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2023-02-01"  and end_date < "2023-05-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2023-05-01"  and end_date < "2023-08-01";

insert overwrite table randome_database.random_table
partition (end_date)
select * from randome_database.random_table_stg
where end_date >= "2023-08-01"  and end_date < "2211-01-01";

Comment: you need to include a snippet of what you have tried already and perhaps any error messages you encountered. That helps improve the quality of the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to get you started

```py
# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateExpansion").getOrCreate()

# Define the list of dates
final_dates = ["2022-11-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-08-01"]

# Read the file
file_path = "/usr/ihitha/var/hive/test_script.py"
file_content = spark.read.text(file_path)

# Filter out the lines that don't contain the end_date condition
filtered_content = file_content.filter(file_content.value.contains('end_date >=') & file_content.value.contains('end_date <'))

# Iterate over final_dates and generate new queries
new_queries = []
for i in range(len(final_dates)-1):
    start_date = final_dates[i]
    end_date = final_dates[i+1]
    new_query = filtered_content.withColumn("value", lit(f'select * from randome_database.random_table_stg where end_date >= "{start_date}" and end_date < "{end_date}";')).select("value")
    new_queries.append(new_query)

# Ensure all DataFrames have the same schema
for query in new_queries:
    query.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")

# Merge the queries
final_queries = spark.sql("SELECT value FROM temp_view UNION ALL SELECT value FROM temp_view")

# Show the final queries
final_queries.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Merge is not working here.

Comment: TypeError: union() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given

Comment: @Reddy I have modified the answer. Let me know if it sorts you out now